# I got error with route defined in laravel-modules

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-models

In Laravel Framework 6.18.35 I use "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^7.2",
and I have an error defining a route to method wrinnten in routes.

In Modules/Pages/Routes/web.php I have :

```
Route::prefix('pages')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
    Route::resource('/admin/page_types', 'Admin\PageTypesController');
});
```

It refers to controller `Modules/Pages/Http/Controllers/Admin/PageTypesController.php` with method:

```
class PageTypesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        \Log::info( '-1 PageTypesController index ::' . print_r(  -1, true  ) );

        return view('pages::admin.page_types.index');
    }
```

with template `Modules/Pages/Resources/views/admin/page_types/index.blade.php`, which has refrence:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-3 mt-1 pl-2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" onclick="javascript:backendPageType.runSearch(oTable); return false;" id="btn_run_search">
    <a onclick="javascript:document.location='{{ route('pages.admin.page_types.create') }}'" class="a_link">
        &nbsp;<small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;( Add )</small>
    </a>
</div>
```

and this raise error :

> Route [pages.admin.page_types.create] not defined. (View: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/lar6/Modules/Pages/Resources/views/admin/page_types/index.blade.php)

I tried several ways of setting the route nane, but failed.

**Modified # 2:**
I see these routes:

```
php artisan route:list

Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types                  | admin.page_types.index   | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types                  | admin.page_types.store   | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types/create           | admin.page_types.create  | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types/{page_type}      | admin.page_types.show    | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types/{page_type}      | admin.page_types.update  | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types/{page_type}      | admin.page_types.destroy | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pages/admin/{admin}/page_types/{page_type}/edit | admin.page_types.edit    | Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageTypesController@edit    | web          |
```

I wonder why so many of "{admin}/" ?
with content in Modules/Pages/Routes/web.php :

```
Route::prefix('pages')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
    Route::resource('admin.page_types', 'Admin\PageTypesController');
});
```

Which is correct syntax?

Comment: Your method is not correct. To create nested routes, Laravel lets you use a dot notation `Route::resource('admin.page_types', 'Admin\PageTypesController');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create **[nested resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources)**, Laravel lets you use a dot notation for resource :

```
Route::resource('admin.page_types', 'Admin\PageTypesController');
```

To check registered routes by running `php artisan route:list` Which outputs a helpful table showing route names along with URLs and controller methods.

Or, create another **group** for **resource** :

```
Route::prefix('pages')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
      Route::resource('page_types', 'Admin\PageTypesController');
  });
});
```

Comment: But which must be url ? With http://local-lar6.com/pages/admin/page_types  I got 404 error...

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list`, you will find the URI

Comment: Do you see your uri on route:list?

Comment: Pls, look at Modified # 2

Comment: I understand what do you want, try the second method. I've updated my answer